# Potree-Core: THREE is not defined

Tags: javascript, npm, import, three.js

I'm working on an offline web based app that other people will also use locally on their machines.

I have an NPM project where I'm using Potree-Core, which in turn uses THREEjs.
the source code doesn't contain an import for THREE, and therefore crashes with a `ReferanceError: THREE is not defined`.

If I manually add `import * as THREE from 'three'` in Potree-Core's source it all works great, but since other people will have to use this app, they will need to first install it with `npm install` which will again install potree-core without `THREE`.

I was told there's a way to define global parameters in the project scope with package.json, but I haven't found anything usefull

Please help?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is super helpful, but you can get it via cloudflare

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r107/three.min.js"></script>
```

then
`window.THREE = require("three");`

Here is this way of importing in action: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/ht94v
Uses node and three js.